# How can I make this function return a sf::Texture? SFML2.0

Tags: c++, textures, sfml

```
void TileSheetManager::setTileSheet(const string textureName)
{
    texture.loadFromFile(textureName);
}

sf::Sprite TileSheetManager::getTile(int left, int top, int width, int height)
{

    sf::IntRect subRect;
    subRect.left = left * 32;
    subRect.top = top * 32;
    subRect.width = width;
    subRect.height = height;

    sf::Sprite sprite(texture, subRect);

    return sprite;
}
```

I need `getTile()` to return a sf::Texture yet I have no idea how I could do it.
I'm using SFML2.0 by the way.

Comment: Is sfml Simple and Fast Multimedia Library?  if so, which version are you using? http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/annotated.php doesn't contain a Texture class. Is it a class you developed on your own?

Comment: I have the library installed, that's how I have sf::Sprite and sf::IntRect. What I'm saying is, is there anyway to crop the tilesheet like sf::Sprite sprite(texture, subRect); but with sf::Texture instead of sf::Sprite?

Comment: Basically I want to be returning a sf::texture of the cropped texture to the subrect.

Comment: I know what you want, but if we can't know what sf:Texture is, it's hard for us to help. The documentation doesn't seem to contain that class, is it something you have developed specifically for your project? Do you mean sf::Image?

Comment: Ok, I just saw that you're using 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Texture.php) and [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php) you should be able to

```
sf::Image fullImage = texture.copyToImage();
sf::Image croppedImage(width, height);
croppedImage.copy(fullImage, 0, 0, subRect);
sf::Texture returnTexture();
returnTexture.LoadFromImage(croppedImage);
```

Comment: With a few tweaks I got no errors for once but now I need to wait for it to compile for a few minutes until I see if it worked or not!

Answer (score 2):

The method `getTile` that you have at the moment does what it's supposed to. You have a tile management class that loads an entire spritesheet, and hands out cropped areas as sprites. Don't change this method just to solve this problem, your `TileSheetManager` class is structured well.

If you want to convert one of your sprites to a texture, you could try the following.

```
// Get a sprite from the Tile Manager.
sf::Sprite mySprite = tileSheetMgr.getTile(1,2,3,4);
// Create a new texture for the sprite returned.
sf::Texture spriteTexture;
// Generate the texture from the sprite's image.
spriteTexture.loadFromImage(*mySprite.getImage());
```